# why height option of tkinter button behaves differently on OSX and windows?

Tags: python, windows, macos, button, tkinter

I have the same code which has the following line

```
self.button = Button(frame, text="CALCOLA", width=28, height=2, command=callback)
```

When I ran the code under OSX the button is a single line button but is separated above and below from the other widgets.
Whereas under windows the button has a height of two lines, hence it is attached above and below to the other items, as in the pictures.

[image: OSX GUI]

[image: Win GUI]

Is there a way to have the same result in both systems?
Furthermore, I noticed that the button width is not exactly the same under both systems, is it possible to have the same behavior also for the width?

Answer (score 2):

Tk widgets are supposed to have a "native look and feel", although they are a bit outdated. So it is intentional that they look different. If you want everything to look similar cross-platform, one option would be to use the canvas, although that would require a lot of work. I would focus on making it look acceptable/good on both platforms, instead of making it look completely similar.

However, the width of the widget is based on characters not pixels. If you roughly estimate, both fit about 28 characters (OSX seems to have a bit more margin on all sides). So fonts are important.

Make sure the default font/font-size is exactly the same.

```
import Tkinter
import tkFont

root = Tk()
tkFont.nametofont("TkDefaultFont").actual()
```

My Windows 7:
{'family': 'Segoe UI', 'weight': 'normal', 'slant': 'roman', 'overstrike': 0, 'underline': 0, 'size': 9}

My Windows Server 2008:
{'family': 'Tahoma', 'weight': 'normal', 'slant': 'roman', 'overstrike': 0, 'und
erline': 0, 'size': 8}

There are more default fonts e.g.: "TkTextFont"

If you use the same font it should look much more similar.

[image]

The first two buttons with "CALCOLA" are on my Windows 7 System. The first one with the default system settings. The second one with the following settings:

```
root.option_add("*Button.Font", "Tahoma 8 bold roman normal underline")
Tkinter.Button(root, text="CALCOLA").pack()
```

The third button with "CALCOLA", is a button from my Windows 2008 Server System with the default settings. You can also change the background color:

```
root.option_add("*Button.Background", "white")
Tkinter.Button(root, text="CALCOLA").pack()
```

You can also change the background for all new elements:

```
root.option_add("*Background", "blue")
Tkinter.Button(root, text="CALCOLA").pack()
Tkinter.Label(root, text="CALCOLA").pack()
```

UPDATE:

both the width and the height are based on the fonts, the margin between the text and the edges is based on the OS specific themes. But you can configure even more settings, e.g. for a button:

'highlightThickness'
'text'
'image'
'compound'
'height'
'borderWidth'
'padY'
'padX'
'font'
'activeForeground'
'activeBackground'
'underline'
'width'
'state'
'highlightColor'
'textVariable'
'overRelief'
'takeFocus'
'-borderwidth'
'foreground'
'-background'
'repeatInterval'
'repeatDelay'
'background'
'-foreground'
'bitmap'
'highlightBackground'
'disabledForeground'
'wrapLength'
'default'
'cursor'
'command'
'relief'
'anchor'
'justify'

Setting atleast padY and padX to a similar value should also help making the appearance more similar in both OS's. You can get the current settings like this:

```
print(
    root.option_get("padY", "Button"),
    root.option_get("padX", "Button"),
)
```

Comment: everythin is very nice but how about the height? I'll try with the font for the width, but this does not fix the height.

Comment: sorry I just saw your update, I'll try it very soon and I'll let you know.